# Php pdo login script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i create login script with pdo but i have some problem

```
if($_POST['giris']){
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
        username = :userg,
        pw = :pwg");
        $result = $query->execute(array(
        'userg' => $_POST['userg'],
        'pwg' => $_POST['pwg'],
        ));

        if($result > 0){
            echo "ok";
        }else{
            echo "no";
        }

    }
```

İ think i  if result problem i how fix ? i want if username = username and pw go login.

Comment: `WHERE username = :userg,
        pw = :pwg"` you're using a comma instead of an logical operator http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html. Checking for errors on PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have signaled the syntax error. What you have now is UPDATE syntax.

Comment: Plus, we have no way of knowing if you did successfully connect using the same API, or that your POST arrays hold values. Check for errors there also.

Comment: Actually query languages are the ones which is most similar to human language...I want username = username "AND" pw go login..As @Fred mentioned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
    username = :userg,
    pw = :pwg");
    $result = $query->execute(array(
    'userg' => $_POST['userg'],
    'pwg' => $_POST['pwg'],
    ));
```

To this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
    username = :userg AND pw = :pwg");
    $query->bindParam(':userg', $_POST['userg']);
    $query->bindParam(':pwg', $_POST['pwg']);
    $query->execute();
```

Thanks to Fred-ii- for catching my error in the select query!
Change:

```
if($result > 0){
        echo "ok";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
```

To:

```
$count = $query->rowCount();
if($count==1){
echo "ok";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
```

Comment: i change okey work your code. but i login try so  if($result > 0){
            echo "ok";
        }else{
            echo "no";
        } here problem i login and print me "ok" of us. i  not = i need print no how?

Comment: @ChrisG `username = :userg,
    pw = :pwg` should read as `username = :userg AND 
    pw = :pwg` - Using a comma is UPDATE syntax.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks Chris :) *Cheers* same for the other one we were on earlier ;-) couple of pairs of Eagle eyes lol

Answer (score 0):

try this query [SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :user **AND** pw = :pw]

```html
if($_POST['giris']){

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :user AND pw = :pw');
$req->execute(array('user' => $_POST['userg'], 'pw' =>  $_POST['pwg'] ));
   
    if($result > 0){
        echo "ok";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
 }
```